# Maven "Invalid content was found starting with element"

Tags: java, maven

Not sure why this happens, but I'm trying to fix an issue with signed jars in a minecraft plugin, I added this fix and it errors out at 
The pom code that is breaking is:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>unpack-dependencies</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <excludeScope>system</excludeScope>
                    <excludes>META-INF/*.SF</excludes>
                    <excludes>META-INF/*.DSA</excludes>
                    <excludes>META-INF/*.RSA</excludes>
                    <excludeGroupIds>junit,org.mockito,org.hamcrest</excludeGroupIds>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

The error is:

```
Invalid content was found starting with element '{"http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":plugin}'. One of '{"http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":parent, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":prerequisites, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":issueManagement, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":ciManagement, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":inceptionYear, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":mailingLists, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":developers, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":contributors, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":profiles, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":modules, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":pluginRepositories, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":reports, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":dependencyManagement, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":distributionManagement}' is expected
```

Does anyone know what I can do? I'm not good at coding, by the way

As requested by someone, here's the full pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>me.totalfreedom</groupId>
    <artifactId>TotalFreedomMod</artifactId>
    <version>2020.12</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <tfm.build.codename>Antaeus</tfm.build.codename>
        <jar.finalName>${project.name}</jar.finalName>
        <timestamp>${maven.build.timestamp}</timestamp>
        <maven.build.timestamp.format>MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm</maven.build.timestamp.format>
    </properties>

    <name>TotalFreedomMod</name>
    <description>Server modification for the TotalFreedom server</description>
    <url>https://github.com/AtlasMediaGroup/TotalFreedomMod</url>

    <licenses>
        <license>
            <name>TotalFreedom General License</name>
            <url>https://github.com/TotalFreedom/License/blob/master/LICENSE.md</url>
        </license>
    </licenses>

    <organization>
        <name>TotalFreedom</name>
        <url>https://totalfreedom.me</url>
    </organization>

    <scm>
        <connection>scm:git:git@github.com:TFPatches/TotalFreedomMod.git</connection>
        <developerConnection>scm:git:git@github.com:TFPatches/TotalFreedomMod.git</developerConnection>
        <url>git@github.com:TFPatches/TotalFreedomMod.git</url>
    </scm>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>jitpack.io</id>
            <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>CodeMC</id>
            <url>https://repo.codemc.org/repository/maven-public/</url>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>nms-repo</id>
            <url>https://repo.codemc.org/repository/nms/</url>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>spigot-repo</id>
            <url>https://hub.spigotmc.org/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>enginehub</id>
            <url>https://maven.enginehub.org/repo/</url>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>elmakers-repo</id>
            <url>https://maven.elmakers.com/repository/</url>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>sk89q-snapshots</id>
            <url>https://maven.sk89q.com/artifactory/repo</url>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>jcenter</id>
            <name>jcenter-bintray</name>
            <url>https://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>playpro</id>
            <url>https://maven.playpro.com/</url>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>md_5-public</id>
            <url>https://repo.md-5.net/content/groups/public/</url>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>dmulloy2-repo</id>
            <url>https://repo.dmulloy2.net/nexus/repository/public/</url>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>sk89q-repo</id>
            <url>https://maven.sk89q.com/repo/</url>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>papermc</id>
            <url>https://papermc.io/repo/repository/maven-public/</url>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>rayzr-repo</id>
            <url>https://cdn.rawgit.com/Rayzr522/maven-repo/master/</url>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>ess-repo</id>
            <url>https://ci.ender.zone/plugin/repository/everything/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.11</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.15</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.speedxx</groupId>
            <artifactId>Mojangson</artifactId>
            <version>1957eef8d6</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bstats</groupId>
            <artifactId>bstats-bukkit</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spigotmc</groupId>
            <artifactId>spigot</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.4-R0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.TotalFreedomMC</groupId>
            <artifactId>BukkitTelnet</artifactId>
            <version>541e9fdb84</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.TotalFreedomMC</groupId>
            <artifactId>TF-LibsDisguises</artifactId>
            <version>48f01cf2fe</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sk89q.worldedit</groupId>
            <artifactId>worldedit-bukkit</artifactId>
            <version>7.3.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.ess3</groupId>
            <artifactId>EssentialsX</artifactId>
            <version>2.18.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.dv8tion</groupId>
            <artifactId>JDA</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0_224</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.coreprotect</groupId>
            <artifactId>coreprotect</artifactId>
            <version>19.3</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sk89q.worldguard</groupId>
            <artifactId>worldguard-bukkit</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.papermc</groupId>
            <artifactId>paperlib</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.6</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>me.rayzr522</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsonmessage</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.vexsoftware</groupId>
            <artifactId>votifier</artifactId>
            <version>v1.9</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.goldtreeservers</groupId>
            <artifactId>worldguardextraflags</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.reflections</groupId>
            <artifactId>reflections</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.12</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.27.0-GA</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.TotalFreedomMC</groupId>
            <artifactId>TFGuilds</artifactId>
            <version>db036fb187</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <!-- Filter resources for build.properties -->
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>

        <plugins>
            <!-- Compiler -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <outputFileName>TotalFreedomMod.jar</outputFileName>
                    <compilerVersion>1.8</compilerVersion>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Git describe -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>pl.project13.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>git-commit-id-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>get-the-git-infos</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>revision</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>validate-the-git-infos</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>validateRevision</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <dotGitDirectory>${project.basedir}/.git</dotGitDirectory>
                    <prefix>git</prefix>
                    <dateFormat>yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss</dateFormat>
                    <verbose>false</verbose>
                    <format>properties</format>
                    <failOnNoGitDirectory>false</failOnNoGitDirectory>
                    <failOnUnableToExtractRepoInfo>false</failOnUnableToExtractRepoInfo>
                    <includeOnlyProperties>
                        <includeOnlyProperty>git.commit.id.abbrev</includeOnlyProperty>
                    </includeOnlyProperties>
                    <gitDescribe>
                        <skip>false</skip>
                        <always>false</always>
                        <abbrev>7</abbrev>
                        <dirty>-dirty</dirty>
                        <match>*</match>
                    </gitDescribe>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Antrun -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                        <phase>initialize</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <target>
                                <propertyfile file="${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/build.properties"
                                              comment="Build information. Edit this to your liking.">
                                    <entry key="buildAuthor" default="unknown"/>
                                    <entry key="buildNumber" default="0"/>
                                    <entry key="buildCodeName" value="${tfm.build.codename}"/>
                                    <entry key="buildVersion" value="${project.version}"/>
                                    <entry key="buildDate" value="${timestamp}"/>
                                    <!--suppress UnresolvedMavenProperty -->
                                    <entry key="buildHead" value="${git.commit.id.abbrev}"/>
                                </propertyfile>
                            </target>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Properties -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>initialize</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <files>
                                <file>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/build.properties</file>
                            </files>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Buildnumber -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>create</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>

                <configuration>
                    <buildNumberPropertyName>maven.buildnumber</buildNumberPropertyName>
                    <buildNumberPropertiesFileLocation>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/build.properties
                    </buildNumberPropertiesFileLocation>
                    <format>{0,number,#}</format>
                    <items>
                        <item>buildNumber</item>
                    </items>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Shade -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <minimizeJar>true</minimizeJar>
                            <relocations>
                                <relocation>
                                    <pattern>io.papermc.lib</pattern>
                                    <shadedPattern>me.totalfreedom.totalfreedommod.paperlib</shadedPattern> <!-- Replace this -->
                                </relocation>
                                <relocation>
                                    <pattern>org.bstats</pattern>
                                    <shadedPattern>me.totalfreedom.totalfreedommod</shadedPattern>
                                </relocation>
                            </relocations>
                            <artifactSet>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>commons-io:commons-io</include>
                                    <include>org.apache.commons:commons-lang3</include>
                                    <include>commons-codec:commons-codec</include>
                                    <include>org.reflections:reflections</include>
                                    <include>org.javassist:javassist</include>
                                    <include>me.rayzr522:jsonmessage</include>
                                    <include>io.papermc:paperlib</include>
                                    <include>com.github.speedxx:Mojangson</include>
                                    <include>org.bstats:bstats-bukkit</include>
                                </includes>
                            </artifactSet>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


    <reporting>
        <!-- Checkstyle -->
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <configLocation>checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
                    <failOnViolation>true</failOnViolation>
                    <failsOnError>true</failsOnError>
                    <consoleOutput>true</consoleOutput>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
    <plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>unpack-dependencies</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <excludeScope>system</excludeScope>
                    <excludes>META-INF/*.SF</excludes>
                    <excludes>META-INF/*.DSA</excludes>
                    <excludes>META-INF/*.RSA</excludes>
                    <excludeGroupIds>junit,org.mockito,org.hamcrest</excludeGroupIds>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
    </plugins>
</project>
```

Comment: Please show the full pom you have...

Comment: When I get back on my PC I will do that

Comment: full pom added!

Comment: You already have a section `<build><plugins>`. Just move the additional plugin there.

Comment: Just did this, now have this error: Plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.1.1' not found,

Answer (score 1):

You probably placed the `<plugin>` outside of the `<plugins>` tag.

Comment: there wasn't a <plugins> tag, as it made the same issue, so I thought I didnt need it

Comment: You need to follow the defined xml structure of Maven, which you can see here http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.3/maven-model/maven.html